# Teaching Methods

Tags: teaching-methods, teaching, direct-method

What are the features, pros and cons, and procedures of the different methods of teaching language, such as direct method, grammar-translation, task-based, and audiolingualism, etc?

Comment: This is a very broad question. Could you narrow it down, maybe by presenting the actual problem you are tying to solve?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Language Learning SE. You have come to the right site on the Stack Exchange network, but, as Tommi said, your question is too broad. We already have many other questions about teaching methods such as [What are the main foreign language teaching methods?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/2110/800), [What are the advantages and disadvantages of direct methods (using only the target language)?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/1972/800) and [many other ones](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bteaching-methods%5D+answers%3A1..).

Comment: Could you please reword your question about a specific method you are interested in? If you are interested in more than one method, you can post a separate question about each of them.