# Is the use of mother-tongue in the English class a boon or a bane?

Tags: learning-methods, teaching-methods, teaching

I teach English in a government school where the medium  of instruction  is both English and the regional medium Telugu. The slow learners opt for Telugu medium and they are not able to follow my English unless I resort to the regional medium while teaching English

Some English scholars say that mother tongue can be used judiciously. What is judicious is  difficult to define or decide.

My question is, *whether the use of  mother-tongue in the English class is a boon or a bane*?

Comment: Interesting, if broad, question. Just a quick tip: please don't use the code markup for things besides code (quotes, emphasis). It makes things a lot more difficult for people who use screen readers, such as blind people.

Comment: Could you please read [What are the advantages and disadvantages of direct methods (using only the target language)?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/1972/800) and [Has the “direct method” of language learning been shown to be superior to translation-based methods?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/11/800) and clarify which parts of your question are not addressed in the answers to these two other questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "sink-or-swim" method, that is, teaching entirely in the target language, only works if your students are "swimming." If they are "sinking" in the total immersion environment, they are better off with native-language explanations at key points in the lesson. Unless you know how to ensure student comprehension with total immersion, they will learn more if you use their mother tongue judiciously. This has been my experience as a Spanish teacher.